# Wordpress breaks when I add jQueryUI to it

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site (3.5.1) where I wanted to add a datepicker to my plugin. By default this didn't work so I searched around and found out I had to load the library using `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`. After adding the script I had a datepicker. Perfect.

I wanted to change the widget layout and found out it was broken. I am able to drag around widgets but when they are dropped they 'freeze'. I've tried to turn off my added jQuery library. The widget module was working correctly again, but my datepicker doesn't work anymore.

So, I have this code in functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'change_jquery');

function change_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-core');

    wp_register_script('jquery',        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.0');
    wp_register_script('jquery-ui-core',    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js', false, '1.10.0');
    wp_register_style('jquery-ui-css',  '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css');
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing my problem? Maybe I've declared double libraries? I'm quite new to this and don't have any idea where to search for the problem.

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: What if you *don't deregister* the bundled WP scripts? See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook for your action

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'change_jquery');
```

This likely won't solve your issue but nonetheless it is the correct hook to use for enqueue'ing scripts.

Answer (score 0):

if the datepicker is meant for use on the frontend of the plugin rather than the backend, use the `is_admin()` conditional tag to only load it on front end (not admin panel):

```
function change_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-core');

        wp_register_script('jquery',        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.0');
        wp_register_script('jquery-ui-core',    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js', false, '1.10.0');
        wp_register_style('jquery-ui-css',  '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css');

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'change_jquery');
```

Answer (score 0):

As far is I can tell, this is probably a javascript error. Wordpress is terrible at handling the $-variable of jquery. There are two things you can do:

1) Try adding files in which you replace all the '$' by 'jQuery'. Mind the fact that the 'Q' has to be written in capitals and the 'j' is not a capital. This worked for me. For example:

```
//Original javascript in wordpress.
function some_function(){
    $('#some_id').click('some_function');
}

//Adapted javascript in wordpress.
function function(){
    jQuery('#some_id').click('some_function');
}
```

---

2) You could try creating a no-conflict wrapper in jquery. I haven't tested this out yet, but it should work. You can find more info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers).